# Removing brackts and single quotes from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, brackets

This seems to be asked in several different scenarios, but each time i apply one, it doesn't seem to make a difference to my output.

Goal: i have a csv file that i want to load into a list and then be able to manipulate the values - compare to other values and such.

Program overview: I wrote a program to identify prime numbers. if i find one, i save it into a file and append a lit. if i restart the program, it looks for the csv, loads the contents into a list, and starts processing at the last number in the list

Issue: when i load the file into a list (prime). It loads fine, but i think that it ends up being a nested list. when i print the list for confirmation, the output looks like:

```
The csv file was loaded 
The list consists of: [['2'], ['3'], ['5']]
The highest prime is ['5']
```

The contents of the list throw an error later in the program when i try to manipulate their values - the error message is `"TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"`

*(sorry if this is TMI)*

Here is the code to load the csv - any thoughts?

```
if os.path.isfile(primePath) is True:

    with open(os.path.join(primePath), newline='') as add2list:

        hold = csv.reader (add2list, delimiter=',')
        for row in hold:
            prime.append(row)
        candidate=prime[-1]
        print ("The csv file was loaded")
        print ("The list consists of:", prime)
        print ("The highest prime is", candidate)
```

Comment: what is your question ??

Comment: What are the contents (the actual data, not a description) of the file?

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
>>> a = [['2'], ['3'], ['5']]
>>> b = [int(i[0]) for i in a]
>>> b
[2, 3, 5]
>>>
```

Comment: i tried this and it seemed help ... although, i may not have written the line correctly:

    with open(os.path.join(primePath), newline='') as add2list:

        hold = csv.reader (add2list, delimiter=',')
        for row in hold:
            row=[int(i[0]) for i in hold]
            prime.append(row)
        candidate=prime[-1]


the output was:

The csv file was loaded
The list consists of: [[3, 5]]
The highest prime is [3, 5]

Comment: @FredtheWhale what line are you talking about? could you please be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to parse this list safely:

```py
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> for line in open('file.txt', 'r'):
...     result = int(literal_eval(line)[0][-1])
... 
>>> result
5
```

Where `file.txt` looks like

```
[['2', '3', '5']]
```

Obviously you could implement some better error-handling, but this gives you a start.

Comment: Sorry. Couldn't get to work. Bunch of messy errors.

from ast import literal_eval

    with open(os.path.join(primePath), newline='') as add2list:

        hold = csv.reader (add2list, delimiter=',')
        for row in hold:
            result=int(literal_eval(hold)[0][-1])
            prime.append(result)

output 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\myTest.py", line 65, in <module>
    result=int(literal_eval(hold),[0],[-1])
...
    raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_csv.reader object at 0x02D22770>

Answer (score 0):

Here is additional information:

the issue seems to be around prime.append(row) and how csv.reader pulls information from the csv file.

when i open the csv file in notepad, the file is:
2
3
5

when i first wrote the program, i had it posting all the content to a text file and was comma separated. around 50million, the line became too long and it crashed. i'm trying to rewrite the program to publish to a csv and append the numbers vertically (like in the notepad example)

here is the full program as i currently have it:

```
#!/bin/python3

import time
import os
import csv

i=1
candidate=5
startRows = (2,3,5)
prime = []

folderLocation = "c:/notNow/"    

primeName = "primeNumbers.csv"

primePath=folderLocation + primeName

#check to see if the destination folder has been created
if os.path.isdir(folderLocation) is False:

    # if false, create the folder
    os.makedirs(folderLocation)
    print ("The directory was created")

else:
    print ("The directory exists")


# check to see if the prime file has been created
if os.path.isfile(primePath) is True:
    # if the prime file exists, load it
    # candidate will retain the highest value
    # and that's where the testing will start
    with open(os.path.join(primePath), newline='') as add2list:
        hold = csv.reader (add2list, delimiter=',')
        for row in hold:
            # remove the outer section of brackets from the csv input
            row="".join(row)
            prime.append(row)
        candidate=prime[-1]
        print ("The csv file was loaded")
        print ("The list consists of:", prime)
        print ("The highest prime is", candidate)
        time.sleep(1)

else:

    # Create and populate the prime file

    f = open(primePath, "w", newline = '')
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for x in startRows:
        writer.writerow([x])
        prime.append(x)

    print ("The file was created and populated")
    candidate=prime[-1]
    print ("The highest prime is", candidate)
    time.sleep(1)

    candidate = prime[-2]
    print ("The list consists of:", prime )
    time.sleep(1)


while i > 0:

    i = 1
    x = "True"

    print ("this has been reset")
    print ("i=",i)
    print ("x=",x)
    print ("end of reset message")
    print ("")
    time.sleep(1)


    while x=="True": 
        print ("candidate is", candidate)
        print ("prime to test is", prime[i])
        time.sleep(1)


        print(candidate,"/", prime[i],"=",candidate%prime[i])



        # % (aka modulo) returns the remainder from a division
        if candidate%prime[i] == 0:
            print ("candidate is not prime -->", candidate)
            candidate+=2
            x = "False"

        # increment the counter
        i+=1


        # test for end of the array
        # if this is the end of the array then candidate is prime
        try:    
            test=prime[i]   
            # open the file in append mode

        except:

            with open(os.path.join(primePath), "a") as add2file:
                csv_writer = writer(add2file)
                csv_writer.writerow(str(candidate))
            print ("PRIME IDENTIFIED --->", candidate)

            prime.append(candidate)
            print("ARRAY HAS BEEN UPDATED WITH", candidate)         

            x="False"
            candidate+=2
```

when i run this, i get the following output:

```
The directory exists
The csv file was loaded
The list consists of: ['2', '3', '5']
The highest prime is 5
this has been reset
i= 1
x= True
end of reset message

candidate is 5
prime to test is 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\primeNumberTest.py", line 86, in <module>
    print(candidate,"/", prime[i],"=",candidate%prime[i])
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Thanks for your interest and help. i recognize that there may be other issues in the code. I'm happy / willing to fix those on my own. i just can't seem to figure out  this issue with the data being entered is not able to be used.